# jQuery submit not firing

Tags: jquery, html

I feel stupid for asking this, but why is my .submit not firing an alert?

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttonbar" style="margin-left:10%">
 <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
 <button class="btn btn-success" id="publish">Publish</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#publish').submit(function(){
            alert("hello");
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

When I click "publish" jQuery does not popup with an alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `click` event instead of `submit`

Comment: .submit works only for `form` elements. Either put your buttons inside `form` tags, or if not, use .click event instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is not a `submit` button, It wont have an event called `submit` while it is out of the scope of a `<form>` tag.

Just try with `click` event,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#publish').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    }); 
});
```

or you have to make changes in your html like,

```
<div class="buttonbar" style="margin-left:10%">
 <form>
 <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
 <input class="btn btn-success" id="publish" type="submit" value="Publish"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#publish').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @TravisJ Updated accordingly.

Comment: See [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) ans search for **The type of the button.**

Comment: It's worth noting that the submit button doesn't have a `submit` event. The event is fired on the `<form`>.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a `<button>` rather than an `<input type="submit">`
And you've got no `<form>` for the submit function to act upon (actually, that alone is probably your problem).

Comment: This is definitely the issue. If there was a form, then the button would be implicitly typed as submit. In order to have the handler without using submit, one of the other solutions will still work though.

Comment: Default behavior of button is submit. Problem with OP is that there is no `form`

Comment: @Satpal Can you please link me to one such link.? thank you..! I just misunderstood about it.

Answer (score 2):

Submit is for forms, click is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#publish').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    }); 
});
```

Try on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you have

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#publish').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    }); 
});
```

This does not work for me, because you are binding to the input's submit event. To make this work, I had to set the id attribute of the FORM tag and bind to its submit event.

```
<form id='publishForm'>
   <input type=submit....
</form>

$("#publishForm").submit(function (event) {
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
    event.preventDefault();
 )};
```

This works for me at least :)